# Google App Engine Search API set cursor at a specific position

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using Google App engine search API in my application. I am using cursors for pagination. The problem is when a user requests 1st page and then requests 45th page , how will i set my cursor position to get the 45th page?

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you are looking for.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/queryoptionsclass#QueryOptions_offset